# OpenCV Haar Cascade training parameters and time

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier, cascade-classifier, lbph-algorithm

I have been fiddling around with OpenCV's cascade trainer in an attempt to train my own classifier. The problem is that it has been training for 25+hours now and it is yet to even pass stage 1.

Initially, I ran it with the following command

`nohup opencv_traincascade -data data -vec board.vec -bg bg.txt -numPos 580 -numNeg 1160 -numStages 2 -w 115 -h 153 -featureType LBP &`

After about 24 hours, it wasn't able to get through even stage 1. A look into the [nohup.out](https://pastebin.com/qfaGceCF) file, I realized that the default `precalcValBufSize` was set to 1024Mb. I figured maybe increasing this to 4096Mb will help with the processing so I went ahead and re-started the training with the following command

`nohup opencv_traincascade -data data -vec board.vec -bg bg.txt -numPos 580 -numNeg 1160 -numStages 2 -w 115 -h 153 -featureType LBP -precalcIdxBufSize 4096 -precalcValBufSize 4096 &`

The training has been running for almost 25 hours now and it also hasn't even produced the XML file for stage 0.

A [look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxtSh.jpg) into the process itself states that its using 8284M of virtual memory but 930M of physical memory and [this](https://imgur.com/a/sqPaA) shows all the files currently in use by the process. Its doing a great job burning through my cores but none at producing any results or even letting me know how far its got.

My question(s) is/are, is there any way of making it use more of my actual physical memory in attempt to speed it up? If not, are there any adjustments I need to make on my training dataset?

**Side Note:** *I know the general standard for dataset size is 24x24 but I already tried that out and it was really horrible even after 10 stages.
At that size, [my object's](https://imgur.com/a/91HnO) outline no longer attains its features correctly. At 24x24 or even 48x48 it looks like a giant horizontally distorted blob of black pixels without even some of its unique features being visible.*

Comment: is it stuck in collecting/finding negative samples or does it take so much time to compute the features?

Comment: ok, the choseb size is really unusually big.

Comment: From the nohup result, it seems like it is able to collect all of the negative samples. After looking at [other peoples results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971769/opencv-haar-classifier-result-table-explanation), at least it prints out TRAINING 1-STAGE blah blah blah.. But it doesn't even get there on my trainer

Comment: btw, HAAR is not using "shape" but "texture" so not sure whether HAAR cascades (and LBP) is the right choice for you.

Comment: can you post a screenshot? If using Windows 10 make sure you dont click in the console window because it wil enable a mark+copy mode and pause the application.

Comment: I can't post the actual object so the outline is the closest I can do.. But just imagine the middle portion as having a screen and some logos around the object

Comment: if you try 24x32 window size, will your training reach 2nd stage fast?

Comment: A screenshot of?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147850/discussion-between-eshirima-and-micka).

Answer (score 0):

I bet that the problem is in samples size.
The bigger size requires muuuuch bigger memory buffers and much more time. Detecting features is quite a difficult operation.

You have to minimize your samples (don't forget to rerum `cv_createsamples(...)`). Samples shouldn't be square it may be 25*15 (make sure proportions are saved and the biggest side is about 30px). 
You are using featureType LBP which itself is faster than Haar.